# php include misses variables

Tags: php, variables, include

i have a file `conf.php` that contains defined variables like this

**conf.php**

```
$var1='some value';
$var2='some value';
$var3='some value';
```

i include this file within a function in another file like this

**funcs.php**

```
function myFunction($value1 ,$value2){
include '../includes/conf.php';
echo $var1;  //<= this give and empty string for all vars in conf.php
}
```

i can't seem to figure out the problem

Comment: What happens if you replace `include` with `require`?

Comment: ^ and make sure error reporting is turned on, most likely `conf.php` isn't being included.

Comment: it is really bad practice to use includes in this way.

Comment: hmm i always wondered how php did these kind of includes when the include was done in a certain scope. and furthermore how php would respond if in a different scope i was to say include_once same file

Comment: I agree with @Spudley on this. Bad practice aside, I have posted a solution below.

Comment: What else is in conf.php?  I just performed a simple test like this, and while the variables will be locally scoped to the function they do get imported correctly.  conf.php does correctly have an open tag, right?

Comment: @andrewsi require seems to do the trick. thanks

Comment: @doublesharp i check the php error log, no error about file not being included

Comment: @Spudley what is the best way to do this then, suggestion?

Comment: @Smith - a function should be self-contained; it shouldn't use `include` or `require` to pull variables in from outside. Ideally, it shouldn't even use global variables. Best practice would be to pass the variables required into a function using its function arguments. The include can be done elsewhere, and the variables passed around the function tree as required. This topic is waaay too big to discuss here, but this is fairly a basic point in writing well structured code.

Comment: You should start reading around here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by using the $GLOBALS variable, so in my function, i only needed to do

```
function myFunction($value1 ,$value2){
echo $GLOBALS['value1'];  //<= this works well
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't defining the reference to the root directory. Add

```
__DIR__
```

and it should fix your problem.

```
include __DIR__ . '/../includes/conf.php';
```

If that doesnt work:
I could be mistaken but you might have to declare those variables global within the scope of the calling function (in this case, "myFunction") to access them.
Otherwise my only explanation would be that your include path is incorrect

```
function myfunction(value1, value2){
    include __DIR__ . '/../includes/conf.php';
    global $var1;
    echo $var1;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have to agree with @dudewad, you're function is accessing a locally scoped variable, but declaring inside the function as global will access the globally scoped variable

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want these variables defined as constants? If the values should never change, and you don't want them to ever chagne I would highly recommend it. (Seeing as this is a config file.)
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Otherwise I would see if the file being included is actually loading and seeing if the variables are being referenced locally, you might need to change the variable scope to global as the variables scope might only be to that function.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php